# Embed JavaFX Stage inside JFXPanel (Swing Embed)

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I'm trying to modify an existing JavaFX GUI program to have a feature of "Always Stay On Top". This is not supported in JavaFX at the moment (why!?!?), so some googling has led me to believe I must marry Swing into my JavaFX application in order to achieve this. Not ideal, but OK.

All example patterns I've found use the `JFXPanel` instead of `Stage`, however since my application already exists and was written using JavaFX from the start (zero Swing is in the codebase at the moment), removing the `Stage` from the application starts to become a major re-write just to support this "on top" feature.

How can I embed an existing JavaFX `Stage` in a `JFXPanel` or similar, that will allow me to use the standard `getSomeSwingWindowOrPanel().setAlwaysOnTop(true);` and make my application float on top of all other windows as expected? Am I going about this wrong, ie. is there a better way such as using JNI or something?

Comment: Your stage has a scene which has a root: place the root in the JFXPanel and you should be almost done.

Comment: The stage does have a root - the FXML read in via `FXMLLoader`... however changing `stage` to the `JFXPanel` removes a lot of functionality, such as special javafx event handlers, stage title, and `stage.setOnCloseRequest()` among other things. Is there no way to keep existing program logic and simply apply this functionality to the `Stage`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [setAlwaysOnTop()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setAlwaysOnTop-boolean-) method was added to stages in Java 8u20.

> **public final void setAlwaysOnTop(boolean value)**
>
> Sets the value of the property alwaysOnTop.
>
> **Property description:**
>
> Defines whether this Stage is kept on top of other windows.
>   If some other window is already always-on-top then the relative order between these windows is unspecified (depends on platform).
>
> There are differences in behavior between applications if a security manager is present. Applications with permissions are allowed to set "always on top" flag on a Stage. In applications without the proper permissions, an attempt to set the flag will be ignored and the property value will be restored to "false".
>
> The property is read only because it can be changed externally by the underlying platform and therefore must not be bindable.
>
> **Default value:**
>
> false
>
> **Since:**
>
> JavaFX 8u20

Answer (score 0):

> All example patterns I've found use the JFXPanel instead of Stage, however since my application already exists and was written using JavaFX from the start (zero Swing is in the codebase at the moment), removing the Stage from the application starts to become a major re-write just to support this "on top" feature.

A better way to add "Always Stay On Top" feature (without removing the *Stage*) is:-

**stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);**.

I hope it works for you........

Cheers

[1] http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html

Comment: Hmm... it seems `Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL` is for making a `Stage` float on top of other `Stages`, not all other windows. ie. The JavaFX program will still drop behind your web browser if you were to click on it. I'm trying to make the JavaFX application float on top of all windows; JavaFX, and system windows alike.